# How to exclude packages in sonar only for coverage but not for CheckStyle?

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, emma

I want to exclude some packages only for Emma coverage from sonar report. I have tried like below -Dsonar.coverage.exclusions=ab/cyz/data/perftracking/dao/* 
in Jenkins job configuration, It was not working for me. I am using sonar version 3.4.1, Emma Plug in version 1.3.
-Dsonar.exclusions=ab/cyz/data/perftracking/dao/* is working as expected but it is excluding packages from all sonar metrics.

Is there any way to exclude packages from Emma coverage.
Please help on this.

Thanks you:)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the advice you were looking for, but that is a very old version of the platform, and Emma is deprecated - at least for Java. I suggest you start by upgrading your platform and switching to JaCoCo. Your exclusions should work then.